# Little array puzzle. Explanation not clear

Tags: javascript

Im doing this js set of tests: 
[js-assessment](https://github.com/rmurphey/js-assessment)

One of the test says:

```
  it("you should be able to find all occurrences of an item in an array", function() {
      var result = answers.findAllOccurrences('abcdefabc'.split(''), 'a');

      expect(result.join(' ')).to.be('0 6');
    });
```

I don't get where the `'0 6'` result came from.
The task is to find occurrences of `a`, but in that array there are only two a's.

Comment: Those are the **positions** of the "a" characters in the original string.

Comment: oh didn't see that. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how exactly `findAllOccurrences` is implemented, but seeing the result it must be doing the following:

It takes an Array and a String as input.
And returns an Array of indices of where this input String occurs.

`'abcdefabc'.split('') //=> ["a", "b", "c", ...]` This gets you the Array you use as input for `findAllOccurrences`

`findAllOccurrences` then finds `"a"` on the first (index: 0) and seventh (index: 6) position of this input Array, and returns: `[0, 6]`

`[0, 6].join(" ")` will give you `"0 6"`

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't realize that it was looking to receive the pos, instead of a count.